# docker registry failing due to invalid bucket name

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I am setting up a docker registry with s3.

With keys something like:

```
s3_access_key: _env:AWS_KEY
s3_secret_key: _env:AWS_SECRET
s3_bucket: some-bucket-name
```

however, it it fails every every time saying that upper case is now allowed in bucket names.

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/s3/connection.py", line 58, in check_lowercase_bucketname
    raise BotoClientError("Bucket names cannot contain upper-case " \
BotoClientError: BotoClientError: Bucket names cannot contain upper-case characters when using either the sub-domain or virtual hosting calling format.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to also set:

```
boto_bucket: some-bucket-name
```

At the moment, it seems, also don't forget to set

```
storage_path: <path in the bucket>
```